# On the correct use of fseek

Tags: c, file

The following function is part of a program i took from my C book:

```
    void newRecord( FILE *fptr ) {

         unsigned int account;

         printf("%s", "Enter new account number (1 - 100): ");
         scanf("%d", &account );

         fseek( fptr, ( account - 1 ) * sizeof( struct clientData ), SEEK_SET ); 

         struct clientData client;

         fread( &client, sizeof( struct clientData ), 1, fptr );                        

         if ( client.accNum == 0 ) {

              printf("%s", "Enter lastname, firstname, balance\n? ");
              scanf("%14s%9s%lf", client.lastName, client.firstName, &client.balance);

              client.accNum = account;

              fseek( fptr, ( account - 1 ) * sizeof( struct clientData ), SEEK_SET );

              fwrite( &client, sizeof( struct clientData ), 1, fptr );
         }

         else {
         
              printf( "Account #%d already contains informations.\n", client.accNum );
         }

    }
```

The program manipulates a  `"account.dat"` file created beforehand  and allows you to update, delete, create a new record, each record consisting of data of clients within this `struct`:

```
    struct clientData {

         unsigned int accNum;  //account number
         char lastName[15];
         char firstName[10];
         double balance;
    };
```

Each record from 1 - 100 is beforehand written in the file as `{ 0, "", "", 0.0 }`.

The `FILE *fptr` the function receives is a pointer to the file `"account.dat"` .

I hope i provided enough informations.

My question concerns the use of `fseek`.
I understand it sets `fptr` to the correct position so to write the data in the right line, but why is it used twice?

I know this is correct because the program doesn't work if i omit the second call before `fwrite`, still i don't understand why we should position `fptr` again.

Comment: a) Because using `fread` and `fwrite` advance the file pointer, so you would not be updating the same record. b) Because you *must* do a seek operation when switching between read and write of a file.

Comment: Once you have used `fread`, the file pointer is incremented, so you need to do another `fseek` to reset it to the previous position, otherwise you'll overwrite the next record, and not the one you've just read

Comment: `fread` advances/changes the file pointer, `fseek` is used again to back it up. Essentially what's happening is 1) Set the file pointer at the client data for the specified `account` 2) read that client data (which advances the file pointer) 3) Backup the file pointer to the beginning of that client record and write data to it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I wan't aware of the "b)" part of your comment. Are you sure? Do you have a pointer to the standard or to some other more or less officiel documentation?

Comment: It is a bad example for neglecting to check the account number and the return value from `fseek`, `fread` or `fwrite`. The code is the very opposite of being 'robust'.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't know where in the C standard but in MSVC [fopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170) underneath the file modes it says: *However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there's no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are `fsetpos`, `fseek`, and `rewind`. When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either `fflush` or to a file positioning function.*

Comment: @Jabberwocky: This is specified in [§7.21.5.3 ¶7 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thank you I just found that and was about to post.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I am not sure if you were notified of my previous comment, because I initially notified someone else using the `@` syntax, and only changed this to you in an edit of my comment. Therefore, I am now notifying you with this comment. Please tell me whether you were notified of my previous comment, because it would be interesting to know whether this occurs after a name change in an edit. Of course, this information would only be interesting if you were not following the question, because in that case, you would be notified in any case.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel no, I haven't been notified. Looks like a bug on SO. Just upvoted that comment now. And no, I wasn't following the question.